# ReactJS - dynamically update jsonschema dropdown

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, jsonschema, fetch-api

I've looked through numerous posts and feel like I may be missing something small. I have a jsonschema form with several dropdowns defined before the component class. To populate them, Im using a fetch in `componentDidMount` and pushing the returned value(s) to the enums in the dropdown. Upon render the dropdown is blank, but if I click on another tab and return, the dropdown is populated with the value. How can I get it to populate upon the initial render? Code below.

jsonschema:

```
const schema = {
  type: 'object',
  required: ['contextID'],
  properties: {
    contextID: { type: 'string', title: 'Context ID, enum: [], enumNames: [] }    
  }
}
```

componentDidMount fetch:

```
}).then(function(json) {
  this.setState({contextIDArray: json.List}, () => {
    schema.properties.contextID.enumNames.push(this.state.contextIDArray);
    schema.properties.contextID.enum.push(this.state.contextIDArray);
    console.log("SCHEMA:: ", schema.properties.contextID.enumNames);
  });
}.bind(this)).catch(() => {
  this.setState({
    value: 'no response - cb catch'
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your going to be changing the object in the component it needs to be a state object if you want the DOM to render the changes in that component.  Create a state object, set the state in your constructor and then pass that to your form as a prop once you've updated it.

Something like this in your function:

```
}).then(function(json) {
 this.setState({contextIDArray: json.List}, () => {
 schema.properties.contextID.enumNames.push(this.state.contextIDArray);
schema.properties.contextID.enum.push(this.state.contextIDArray);
this.setState({schemaState: schema});
 });
}.bind(this)).catch(() => {
 this.setState({
   value: 'no response - cb catch'
 })
})
```

then in your render something like:

```
render() {

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <Form
                schema={this.state.schemaState}
            />
        </div>
        )
      }
```

This will repaint the DOM.  Your dropdown should be updated.

Comment: Just what I was looking for, worked great! Was updating the enums for the dropdowns, but guess I wasn't actually pushing that update to the DOM to reflect the changes. Assigning the updated schema to a state object then pointing the form to it as a prop was a simple fix, thanks!